# Can you add line-breaks within CSS rules?

Tags: css, syntax

I know that generally, you’d write something like this:

```
.Something {
  other: thing;
}
```

etc. But, is it okay to instead of having a space after `:`, to have a new line, like the following?

```
.Something {
  background-color:
    #161616;
}
```

And for other things, something like this?

```
.Something {
  padding:
    5px,
    2px,
    2px,
    13px;
}
```

I’m just getting really tired of clucking everything on a single line, and just want to know if this is syntactically valid. I am still reading over the [W3C pages](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-syntax-3/) now, but still haven’t found an answer.

Comment: you can break it into padding-left, padding-right etc. I usually see chrome's developer tools show it that way even if its not written like that.

Comment: Thanks @James K - I have seen that before, but I guess I'm just too lazy. +1 though :)

Comment: `padding` is a bad example. You should just keep that all on one line. Maybe if you were talking about something longer like these, I could see why you'd want a few line breaks: http://leaverou.me/css3patterns/ (and sure enough, *there are* line breaks in there)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

CSS is completely ignorant of white space, format it as you please :)

(In other words, yes and yes.)

Comment: Thank you @lpd! I will accept this answer when it lets me lol (11 minutes).

Answer (score 5):

CSS has no significant white space.

However, your last block should not have commas.

```
.Something {
 padding:
 5px
 2px
 2px
 13px;
}
```

This would work.

Comment: Thank you! I am a C# guy mainly so it's just habit to put commas when separating values lol. Good spot

Answer (score 1):

ya you can use like this.

```
.Something {
 background-color:
 #161616;
}
```

this is syntatically correct and it worked for me. I used like this before.

And why are you putting '**,**' for the second one like below

```
.Something {
 padding:
 5px,
 2px,
 2px,
 13px;
}
```

The '**,**' should not be used for separate the values. you can use space instead.

The only thing in both the cases is **It should ends with semicolon**